# How to format xml and java code as text inside TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I am creating an Android Tutorial Application. I am planning to use `Tabs` to display the `java` and the `xml` code used for that topic.

I thought of using `TextView` and applying the `Java` and `XML` code as text to it.

However I am failing to format the `Java` code, plus I am not able to add xml as text at all as it has tags which are not supported.

Below are snaps from another App and the desired output is what I am looking for.

Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

[image: XML Layout]

[image]

Comment: I recommend using `WebView`. Either pre-convert your Java to HTML before packaging it in the app, or use a JavaScript syntax highlighter. For example, in [the APK edition](https://commonsware.com/Android/apk) of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), my "appinars" show Java, XML, and such as you have them here. I use `WebView` and [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) for displaying that code.

Comment: Any example or reference @CommonsWare?

Comment: Example or reference *for what*? I linked to [the Prism documentation](http://prismjs.com/) in my previous comment. Using Prism in a `WebView` is not significantly different than using any other HTML content in a `WebView` and is not significantly different than is using Prism in a regular Web page for use in a standalone Web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could display your Code in your TextView with `HTML` and style/format it with `CSS`.

Comment: that should be a comment

Comment: Why? It's a valid **answer** to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Suppose you have **HTML code** like this

```
<h2>Title</h2><br>
<p>description here</p>
```

Then in android you can use below code

```
TextView tvTrial=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTrial);
String html="<h2>Title</h2><br> <p>description here</p>";
    tvTrial.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Now any thing you want to display in you view you can store it the string and set it.